# What guarantees are there on the run-time complexity (Big-O) of LINQ methods?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, algorithm, complexity-theory

I've recently started using LINQ quite a bit, and I haven't really seen any mention of run-time complexity for any of the LINQ methods. Obviously, there are many factors at play here, so let's restrict the discussion to the plain `IEnumerable` LINQ-to-Objects provider. Further, let's assume that any `Func` passed in as a selector / mutator / etc. is a cheap O(1) operation.

It seems obvious that all the single-pass operations (`Select`, `Where`, `Count`, `Take/Skip`, `Any/All`, etc.) will be O(n), since they only need to walk the sequence once; although even this is subject to laziness.

Things are murkier for the more complex operations; the set-like operators (`Union`, `Distinct`, `Except`, etc.) work using `GetHashCode` by default (afaik), so it seems reasonable to assume they're using a hash-table internally, making these operations O(n) as well, in general. What about the versions that use an `IEqualityComparer`?

`OrderBy` would need a sort, so most likely we're looking at O(n log n). What if it's already sorted? How about if I say `OrderBy().ThenBy()` and provide the same key to both?

I could see `GroupBy` (and `Join`) using either sorting, or hashing. Which is it?

`Contains` would be O(n) on a `List`, but O(1) on a `HashSet` - does LINQ check the underlying container to see if it can speed things up?

And the real question - so far, I've been taking it on faith that the operations are performant. However, can I bank on that? STL containers, for example, clearly specify the complexity of every operation. Are there any similar guarantees on LINQ performance in the .NET library specification?

More question (in response to comments):
Hadn't really thought about overhead, but I didn't expect there to be very much for simple Linq-to-Objects. The CodingHorror post is talking about Linq-to-SQL, where I can understand parsing the query and making SQL would add cost - is there a similar cost for the Objects provider too? If so, is it different if you're using the declarative or functional syntax?

Comment: Although i cannot really answer your question I want to comment that in general the larges part of the performance will be "overhead" compared to the core functionality. This is of course not the case when you have very large datasets (> 10k items) so im curious in which case you want to know.

Comment: Re: "is it different if you're using the declarative or functional syntax?" - the compiler translates the declarative syntax into the functional syntax so they would be the same.

Comment: "STL containers clearly specify the complexity of every operation"  .NET containers also clearly specify the complexity of every operation.  Linq extensions are akin to STL algorithms, not to STL containers.  Just as when you apply an STL algorithm to an STL container, you need to combine the complexity of the Linq extension with the complexity of the .NET container operation(s) to properly analyze the resultant complexity.  This includes accounting for template specializations, as Aaronaught's answer mentions.

Comment: An underlying question is why Microsoft wasn't more concerned that an IList<T> optimization would be of limited utility, given that a developer would have to rely to undocumented behavior if his code depended on it to be performant.

Comment: AsParallel() on the resulting set List; should give you ~O(1) < O(n)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

There are very, very few guarantees, but there are a few optimizations:

- Extension methods that use indexed access, such as `ElementAt`, `Skip`, `Last` or `LastOrDefault`, will check to see whether or not the underlying type implements `IList<T>`, so that you get O(1) access instead of O(N).
- The `Count` method checks for an `ICollection` implementation, so that this operation is O(1) instead of O(N).
- `Distinct`, `GroupBy` `Join`, and I believe also the set-aggregation methods (`Union`, `Intersect` and `Except`) use hashing, so they should be close to O(N) instead of O(N²).
- `Contains` checks for an `ICollection` implementation, so it *may* be O(1) if the underlying collection is also O(1), such as a `HashSet<T>`, but this is depends on the actual data structure and is not guaranteed.  Hash sets override the `Contains` method, that's why they are O(1).
- `OrderBy` methods use a stable quicksort, so they're O(N log N) average case.

I think that covers most if not all of the built-in extension methods.  There really are very few performance guarantees; Linq itself will try to take advantage of efficient data structures but it isn't a free pass to write potentially inefficient code.

Comment: How about the `IEqualityComparer` overloads?

Comment: @tzaman: What about them?  Unless you use a really inefficient custom `IEqualityComparer`, I can't reason for it to affect the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: Oh, right. I hadn't realized `EqualityComparer` implements `GetHashCode` as well as `Equals`; but of course that makes perfect sense.

Comment: I think Join is O(MN)

Comment: @imgen: Loop joins are O(N * M) which generalizes to O(N²) for unrelated sets. Linq uses hash joins which are O(N + M), which generalizes to O(N). That assumes a halfway decent hash function, but that's hard to mess up in .NET.

Comment: Thanks, that's cool, I didn't know that Join can be this efficient. Good for the tip.

Comment: is `Orderby().ThenBy()` still `N logN` or is it `(N logN) ^2` or something like that?

Comment: What about `ThenBy()` ?

Comment: OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...) sequence question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41213076/4014106)

Comment: it seems `Skip` does not follow what you claimed. it seems to be `O(n)` http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,90ccdbd47b57182e,references

Comment: never mind, new source looks fine. https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Skip.cs,12

Comment: AsOrdered() will preserve the ordering during parallel optomizations on resulting setlist for optomizations on multi-processing use... AsParallel()

Comment: Does `SortedDictionary.Keys.First/Last` utilize the underlying red-black tree to get min/max?

Answer (score 15):

I've long known that `.Count()` returns `.Count` if the enumeration is an `IList`.

But I was always a bit weary about the run-time complexity of the Set operations: `.Intersect()`, `.Except()`, `.Union()`.

Here's the decompiled BCL (.NET 4.0/4.5) implementation for `.Intersect()` (comments mine):

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> IntersectIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
  Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
  foreach (TSource source in second)                    // O(M)
    set.Add(source);                                    // O(1)

  foreach (TSource source in first)                     // O(N)
  {
    if (set.Remove(source))                             // O(1)
      yield return source;
  }
}
```

Conclusions:

- the performance is O(M + N)
- the implementation *doesn't* take advantage when the collections *already are* sets. (It may not be necessarily straightforward, because the used `IEqualityComparer<T>` also needs to match.)

For completeness, here are the implementations for `.Union()` and `.Except()`.

Spoiler alert: they, too, have **O(N+M)**  complexity.

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> UnionIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
  Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
  foreach (TSource source in first)
  {
    if (set.Add(source))
      yield return source;
  }
  foreach (TSource source in second)
  {
    if (set.Add(source))
      yield return source;
  }
}


private static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
  Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
  foreach (TSource source in second)
    set.Add(source);
  foreach (TSource source in first)
  {
    if (set.Add(source))
      yield return source;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

All you can really bank on is that the Enumerable methods are well-written for the general case and won't use naive algorithms. There is probably third-party stuff (blogs, etc.) that describe the algorithms actually in use, but these are not official or guaranteed in the sense that STL algorithms are.

To illustrate, here is the reflected source code (courtesy of ILSpy) for `Enumerable.Count` from System.Core:

```
// System.Linq.Enumerable
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    checked
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        }
        ICollection<TSource> collection = source as ICollection<TSource>;
        if (collection != null)
        {
            return collection.Count;
        }
        ICollection collection2 = source as ICollection;
        if (collection2 != null)
        {
            return collection2.Count;
        }
        int num = 0;
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                num++;
            }
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it goes to some effort to avoid the naive solution of simply enumerating every element.

Comment: iterating through the whole object to get the Count() if it's an IEnnumerable seems pretty naive to me...

Comment: @Zonko: I don't understand your point. I've amended my answer to show that `Enumerable.Count` doesn't iterate unless there is no obvious alternative. How would you have made it less naive?

Comment: Well, yes, the methods are implemented in the most efficient way given the source. However, the most efficient way is sometimes a naive algorithm, and one should be careful when using linq because it hides the real complexity of calls. If you are not familiar with the underlying structure of the objects you are manipulating, you could easily use the wrong methods for your needs.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Why arrays aren't handled ? It is same for ElementAtOrDefault method http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,0bd04e5c179c3c7d

Comment: @Freshblood They are. (Arrays implement ICollection.) Don't know about ElementAtOrDefault, though. I'm guessing arrays also implement ICollection<T>, but my .Net is quite rusty these days.

Comment: @Freshblood this is an extension method to IEnumerable<>. Arrays should be in its own extension method.

Comment: @gldraphael No arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>` and use Linq just like other collections.

Comment: @MarceloCantos I was specifically talking about this statement _Arrays should be in its own extension method_  which sounds like the writer thinks arrays don't use Linq extension methods like other collections.  I'm well aware that arrays implement `ICollection` and will be efficiently used by many Linq methods.

Comment: @juharr agreed, sorry, I didn't parse the context correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I just broke out reflector and they do check the underlying type when `Contains` is called.

```
public static bool Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value)
{
    ICollection<TSource> is2 = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (is2 != null)
    {
        return is2.Contains(value);
    }
    return source.Contains<TSource>(value, null);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is "it depends".  it depends on what type the underlying IEnumerable is.  i know that for some collections (like collections that implement ICollection or IList) there are special codepaths that are used, However the actual implementation is not guaranteed to do anything special.  for example i know that ElementAt() has a special case for indexable collections, similarly with Count().  But in general you should probably assume the worst case O(n) performance.

In generaly i don't think you are going to find the kind of performance guarantees you want, though if you do run into a particular performance problem with a linq operator you can always just reimplement it for your particular collection.  Also there are many blogs and extensibility projects which extend Linq to Objects to add these kinds of performance guarantees.  check out [Indexed LINQ](http://i4o.codeplex.com/)  which extends and adds to the operator set for more performance benefits.