# The Big O of Distinct() method with a custom IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, linq, big-o

Anyone knows the Big O of the algorithm used in the `Distinct()` method, with a custom `IEqualityComparer`?

Comment: In what terms? complexity? time? length? what?

Comment: @jer, Big O doesn't define such things.

Comment: Basically approaching `O(n*c)`, where `c` is the complexity of what you are doing in a comparer.

Comment: It fully depends on what you are comparing, comparing an int will take less time than comparing two chess-board positions... Also you say its a >>custom<< IEqualityComparer that means you are the only one who knows what it does... If you want an estimate, show us the code.

Comment: @Filip, I know, but these days, programmers tend to use it all over the place in various contexts, therefore I asked for clarification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What guarantees are there on the run-time complexity (Big-O) of LINQ methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799427/what-guarantees-are-there-on-the-run-time-complexity-big-o-of-linq-methods)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an equal question here on SO about "[What guarantees are there on the run-time complexity (Big-O) of LINQ methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799427/what-guarantees-are-there-on-the-run-time-complexity-big-o-of-linq-methods)"

See this section in the answer about distinct:

> Distinct, GroupBy Join, and I believe
>   also the set-aggregation methods
>   (Union, Intersect and Except) use
>   hashing, so they should be close to
>   O(N) instead of O(N²).