# Validate property name (checking for illegal characters)

Tags: c#, regex, validation, properties, typebuilder

For marshalling purpose and automatic type building with native API, I need to validate field names for some structure during runtime. The naming rules on native side are the same as in C# (no whitespace, no special characters like *&*, *é*, *, *.*).

Is there a standard regex pattern for that ?

*NB: As  workaround I'm thinking of building static method around [`DeclareProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2sd82fz7(v=vs.110).aspx) in [`TypeBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) just for name validation purpose.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to remove all special characters from string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303420/regex-to-remove-all-special-characters-from-string)

Comment: [A lot of Unicode characters (especially accented letters like `é`) are perfectly valid identifier names in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: @CodeCaster Damned ... it's true ... never ever tried, but true ... so definitly won't let `Typebuilder.DeclareProperty` do the validation for me.

Comment: have you tried a simple google search here is a link for example that could help you in getting started in regards to using `RegEx` of course there are other built in string functions like `.Contains` in .net you can utilize as well 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350801/check-string-for-invalid-characters-smartest-way

Comment: @MethodMan I know about regex, just wanted to know if there was a standard pattern to use for name validation instead of reinventing the wheel ... but ok ... I will reinvent.

Comment: @CitizenInsane I understand your point but what is valid for some may be considered as invalid for others so I would venture out to say the answer to your question is no.. sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be enough for what I want so far:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9\_]*$
```

Comment: An identifier can also start with an `_`, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names

Comment: @RemiDespres-Smyth You're right ... I removed `_` because targeted API was Matlab MxArray (Matlab does no allow names starting with `_`, nevertheless it's API doesn't make the test so you can create invalid names if not careful).

Answer (score 1):

So do you want to remove the illegal characters (black list) or just check if the identifier is valid? For valid characters, you might use something like:

```
// Match an identifier - Matches "type1" but not &type1" or "#define".
\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b
```

Here is the [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) (although it is for Visual Studio).
Here is the [Regex Patterns reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).