# Sort an array and return all number that are smaller then X

Tags: linq

Using linq, How can I sort an array and after that return all numbers that are smaller then X

For sorting I use that:(is it a good way?)

> var sorted = (from number in array orderby number ascending select number).ToArray();

So i have it sorted in 'sorted' array.

how can i return all numbers in it that are smaller then X.

Comment: Can you please post the line? I am new to LINQ.

Comment: Tim Schmelter answered below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to sort *before* you filter? That is less efficient than to filter first and order the rest:

```
var sorted = array.Where(i => i < x).OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
```

or in query syntax:

```
var sorted = (from i in array
              where i < x
              orderby i
              select i).ToArray();
```

[Order of LINQ extension methods does not affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110013/order-of-linq-extension-methods-does-not-affect-performance) (the title is misleading, actually `OrderBy` is one of the exceptions where the order matters as E.Lippert explains in his answer)

Comment: How can I 'measure' the complexity in that approach?

Comment: @slash1z: I assume it's **O(n)** since `Enumerable.Where` needs to enumerate the array to find all numbers lower than `x`. The rest will by  ordered by `Enumerable.OrderBy` with **O(N log N)** complexity.

Comment: Can you advise how to look at the complexity of that `(from number in array orderby number descending select number).Distinct()`, it's O(n) cause its is going through each value in the array like a simple loop, The Distinct() or the Where() clause are not adding more complexity, right?

Comment: @slash1z: I think so, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799427/what-guarantees-are-there-on-the-run-time-complexity-big-o-of-linq-methods

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = from n in array
             where n < value
             orderby n
             select n;
```

Or in Method syntax:

```
var result = array.Where(n => n < value).OrderBy(n => n);
```

You can use also use [TakeWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile.aspx) if you already have sorted array

```
var result = sortedArray.TakeWhile(n => n < value);
```

Keep in mind that it's better to filter sequence before sorting. Why? Because when you do sorting all items are stored in internal sorted structure. So, the less items you have to sort, the more quickly your code works (and uses less memory).