# C# foreach to linq

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I was wondering if there wasn't an optimal way for this code.

```
List<CollectionFormFieldRecord> dataFields = new List<CollectionFormFieldRecord>();
foreach (CollectionRelationModel relation in relations)
{
     foreach (var field in visibleFields)
     {
          if (field.SourceCollectionsID == relation.ChildCollectionID)
            dataFields.Add(field);
     }
}
```

When a field (visibleFields) has a `SourceCollectionsID` that exists in the relations list then the field must be added to a separated list.

I tried somethings with LINQ but didn't know how to compare a property with a property in a list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17323838/442444

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare Two Lists Via One Property Using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323804/compare-two-lists-via-one-property-using-linq)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can be similar to this

```
var dataFields = dataFields .Where(f => relations.Any(r => f.SourceCollectionsID ==r.ChildCollectionID))
                .ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using linq

```
dataFields = (from relation in relations 
                    from field in visibleFields 
                    where field.SourceCollectionsID == relation.ChildCollectionID 
                    select field).Select(field => field).ToList();
```

but I do prefer using foreaches instead

Comment: Why do you prefer foreaches? I thought linq could be more performant?

Comment: @PJDW no it isn't http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14197/is-the-linq-version-faster-than-the-foreach-one

Answer (score 2):

The code you showed us has complexity of O(N square). Try to use .Join method, so you will have complexity close to O(N) due to hashing. The code you should use is

```
dataFields = visibleFields.Join(relations, vF => vF.SourceCollectionsID, r => r.ChildCollectionID, (visibleField, relation) => visibleField).ToList();
```

For better understand about complexity look at my answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824510/select-multiple-records-based-on-list-of-ids-with-linq/26716193#26716193)