# How to get property values from multiple Ids

Tags: c#, umbraco7

I have a compare function which has a 3 items to compare.
My problem is how can I get their properties with their corresponding `ID`.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public List<Compares> CompareValues(string ids)
{
    var result = new List<Compares>();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ids))
    {
        var nodes = ids.Split(',').ToList().TypedContentList();
        return nodes.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(x.Id, x.GetPropertyValue<string>("title"))).ToList();
        /// Error : Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List....
    }

    return result;
}
```

The full message is as follows:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Jin

Comment: Can you post the values of `ids` and `nodes`? Also, your expected output.

Comment: Can you provide the full error message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824542/8435038 does that look like what you need? Your question doesn't make it easy to know what you want lol.

Comment: @Bijay data: _/// Umbraco/Api/Search/ComparisonKeyValues?ids=2874,2875,2876_

Comment: @John _Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyProj.Models.Api.Compares>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProj.Models.Api.Compares>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)_

Comment: @Dave, but how can I get the IDs? sorry, I am new in C#. THanks

Comment: Once you've split them it will be a List of Strings, so you need to convert your List<string> to List<int> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6201377/8435038

Comment: how can I split them? like this _var listOfIds = ids.Split(',').ToList()_ ? Thanks.. sorry for my noob question, I really new in C# :(

Answer (score 0):

Your function expects to return a `List<Compares>`.

This line:

```
return nodes.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(x.Id, x.GetPropertyValue<string>("title"))).ToList();
```

Is NOT returning `List<Compares>`, it's returning a list of `KeyValuePairs<int,string>` by the look of it.