# Using join method on Entity Framework I Get Error with big id lists filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I got this error

> Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.

when I use join for listing data from the database by long list.

This is my code:

```cs
public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<ResultModel>>>AddRequest(List<dto> DTOs)
{
   List<ResultModel> results = new List<ResultModel>();
   //repo is a IQueryable 
   var repo = UnitOfWork.Repository<InfoRequest>();
      
   #region 
   List<long> poolDetailIds = DTOs.Where(x => x.PoolDetailId.HasValue).Select(x => x.PoolDetailId.Value).ToList();
   var existingInfoRequests = repo.Join(poolDetailIds , r => r.PoolDetailId, il => il, (r, il) => r);
   var response = existingInfoRequests.ToList();

   if(response.Count > 0)
      return results;
}
```

`poolDetailIds` can has 10k or 20k ids. For this situation I am using join. When I have 20 id's I don't get any error. But when ı ask with 5k id's I get error.

I using .Net Version 4.7.1 . `poolDetailIds` a parameters . İt's contains id list and I want to create a query and to match all  . Then get all data objects . I'am using `contains` but I think it is not has good performance then ı find this: [Select multiple records based on list of Id's with linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824510/select-multiple-records-based-on-list-of-ids-with-linq)

Comment: What is repo? Which type?

Comment: repo is my data table(InfoRequest) from postgre

Comment: Whole table from database?

Comment: This shouldn't actually compile. Not all code paths return a value.

Comment: this is not important I get eror when ı want take list from InfoRequest

Comment: At 5k ids, given all them would be not null, how big would the expected resultset be in Bytes?

Comment: I don't think that `Enumerable.Join` uses a lot of stack here. Something is missed here. Also you can use just `repo.Where(x => poolDetailIds.Contains(x.PoolDetailId))`, but better make `poolDetailIds` as `HashSet<long>`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv `repo.Where(x => poolDetailIds.Contains(x.PoolDetailId))` wouldn't that likely exceed what EF can handle in a `Contains` at 5-20 000 ids?

Comment: @MehmetResulAkyuz, again which type has `repo` variable? It is `IQueryable`?

Comment: @Fildor, it will not translate `Join` also, so I assume OP works with `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Why didn't you join directly two tables(repo ,poolDetailIds ).Now you bring whole into RAM and then join?

Comment: _"so I assume OP works with IEnumerable"_ - fair point ...

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes repo is IQueryable.

Comment: @MehmetResulAkyuz, EF cannot translate `Join` with local collection. EF supports only `Contains` with local collections. Which EF Version? Update question with all missed details.

Comment: _"EF supports only Contains with local collections"_ and the amount of Ids in that collection is finite and actually smaller than one might think. So, in case you have really really many ids, you may experience long runtimes or even errors.