# An Optimized algorithm to make a distinct array

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

I'm looking for an optimized algorithm that give an array (or list) of a struct that I wrote and remove duplicated elements and return it.
I know I can do it by a simple algorithm with complexity of O(n^2); But I want a better algorithm.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no reason to re-invent the wheel. Default implementation of `Distinct()` is already optimized. Use it and be happy.

Comment: Does the algorithm need to be _stable_ (i.e. keep the surviving elements in the original order)?

Comment: @Nik : you'r right. I edited my quesion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For practical use LINQ's `Distinct` is the simplest solution. It uses a hashtable based approach, probably very similar to the following algorithm.

If you're interested in how such an algorithm would look like:

```
IEnumerable<T> Distinct(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    var alreadySeen=new HashSet<T>();
    foreach(T item in sequence)
    {
        if(alreadySeen.Add(item))// Add returns false if item was already in set
            yield return;
    }
}
```

If there are `d` distinct elements and `n` total elements then this algorithm will take `O(d)` memory and `O(n)` time.

Since this algorithm uses a hashset, it requires well distributed hashes to achieve `O(n)` runtime. If the hashes suck, the runtime can degenerate to `O(n*d)`

Answer (score 3):

This runs in close to O(N) time:

```
var result = items.Distinct().ToList();
```

[EDIT]

Since there is no documented proof from Microsoft that it is O(N) time, I did some timings with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            test(1000);
            test(10000);
            test(100000);
        }

        private void test(int n)
        {
            var items = Enumerable.Range(0, n);
            new Action(() => items.Distinct().Count())
                .TimeThis("Distinct() with n == " + n + ": ", 10000);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }

    static class DemoUtil
    {
        public static void TimeThis(this Action action, string title, int count = 1)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                action();

            Console.WriteLine("Calling {0} {1} times took {2}",  title, count, sw.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

The results are:

```
Calling Distinct() with n == 1000:   10000 times took 00:00:00.5008792
Calling Distinct() with n == 10000:  10000 times took 00:00:06.1388296
Calling Distinct() with n == 100000: 10000 times took 00:00:58.5542259
```

The times are increasing approximately linearly with `n`, at least for this particular test, which indicates that an O(N) algorithm is being used.

Comment: Probably true but do you have a reference? MSDN doesn't specify anything.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: It would be real daft to not do it in O(N) ;p

Comment: @HenkHolterman Only this StackOverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799427/what-guarantees-are-there-on-the-run-time-complexity-big-o-of-linq-methods

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm pretty sure `Distinct` uses the obvious `HashSet<T>` based approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the array in **O(NlogN)** time, and compare adjacent elements to erase duplicate elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HashSet with complexity of O(N):

```
List<int> RemoveDuplicates(List<int> input)
{
    var result = new HashSet<int>(input);
    return result.ToList();
}
```

But it will increase memory usage.