# Test if all values in a list are unique

Tags: c#

I have a small list of bytes and I want to test that they're all different values.
For instance, I have this:

```
List<byte> theList = new List<byte> { 1,4,3,6,1 };
```

What's the best way to check if all values are distinct or not?

Comment: As this is a typical class room question, I will answer with a question. How would you do it if it was sorted?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

```
bool isUnique = theList.Distinct().Count() == theList.Count();
```

Comment: Just curious: what are the space and time requirements of this?

Comment: @dtb [should be about O(N)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799427/what-guarantees-are-there-on-the-run-time-complexity-big-o-of-linq-methods). Of course, considering this is a "small list", it will be lightning-fast with almost any algorithm. IMO this wins on readability and conciseness, and since speed's not an issue, that makes it perfect.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter answer was 4x faster while using the HashSet. This approach would be good for everyday usage, but for larger set like in millions, HashSet should be used.

Answer (score 98):

Here's another approach which is more efficient than `Enumerable.Distinct` + `Enumerable.Count` (all the more if the sequence is not a collection type). It uses a `HashSet<T>` which eliminates duplicates, is very efficient in lookups and has a count-property:

```
var distinctBytes = new HashSet<byte>(theList);
bool allDifferent = distinctBytes.Count == theList.Count;
```

or another - more subtle and efficient - approach:

```
var diffChecker = new HashSet<byte>();
bool allDifferent = theList.All(diffChecker.Add);
```

[`HashSet<T>.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx) returns `false` if the element could not be added since it was already in the `HashSet`.  `Enumerable.All` stops on the first "false".

Comment: so simple and obvious, why didn't I think about it first :) I used this one-liner in unit test to confirm 10 million elements generated by my awesome code are really unique `Assert.IsTrue(samples.Add(AwesomeClass.GetUnique()));`. They were and are :)  +1 for you Tim :)

Comment: i have tried your answer on this question but it is not working sir:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941162/how-to-break-from-the-loop-when-adding-values-to-the-list-object-which-is-distin/34941302?noredirect=1#34941302

Comment: Should be this: `bool allDifferent = theList.All(s => diffChecker.Add(s))`

Comment: No, not needed. In this case you can pass the delegate directly

Comment: If you use [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)'s `ToHashSet` extension method, the first version of this is even easier.

Comment: Note that make this work with a (custom) none generic `IEqualityComparer` you have to rely on `Hashtable`. As `Hashtable.Add` is a `void`, you have to keep a counter. Than you're done, if adding a new item of your list did not increase the size of your `Hashtable`. With a generic `IEqualityComparer<T>` @Rango's solution is extremely elegant.

Comment: I tried all three approaches in a benachmark and realized, that the one with `new HashSet<byte>(theList)` seems to be the fastest, even with very small lists with only 25 entries.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Here's my test scenario: https://dotnetfiddle.net/n9mlRX Feel free to fork and modify it and share your results. **PS:** In my project, the lists will most likely be unique. When you comment-out the shuffle section in my code, you can see, that the middle version will always outperform the last one.

Comment: @AndréReichelt - I just opened your code and the third scenario (`List.All(HashSet.Add)`) seems to be much faster than the other two in almost all cases

Comment: @TimSchmelter Wow, passing the delegate directly is so much cleaner! Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 13):

Okay, here is the most efficient method I can think of using standard .Net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Extension
{
    public static bool HasDuplicate<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        IEqualityComparer<T> comparer,
        out T firstDuplicate)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(comparer);
        
        (bool result, firstDuplicate) = HasDuplicateImplementation(source, comparer);
        
        return result;
    }
    
    public static bool HasDuplicate<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        out T firstDuplicate)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
        var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        
        (bool result, firstDuplicate) = HasDuplicateImplementation(source, comparer);
        
        return result;
    }
    
    private static (bool, T) HasDuplicateImplementation<T>(
        IEnumerable<T> source,
        IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        var checkBuffer = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
        foreach (var t in source)
        {
            if (!checkBuffer.Add(t))
            {
                return (true, t);
            }
        }
        
        return (false, default);
    }
}
```

essentially, what is the point of enumerating the whole sequence twice if all you want to do is find the first duplicate.

Comment: Nice adding a duplicate value out return, quite useful for validation

Comment: I have tested 3 solutions here and this is indeed the most efficient on this page. A few typos in there though (eg `sequence` should be `source`). But works great once these are fixed

Comment: @mikenelson, that should be better

Comment: For readability, I think it should be `if (!checkBuffer.Add(t)) { firstDuplicate = t; return true }` in the loop.

Answer (score 10):

The similar logic to `Distinct` using `GroupBy`:

```
var isUnique = theList.GroupBy(i => i).Count() == theList.Count;
```

Comment: This is useful if you want to check uniqueness with respect to a property `theList.GroupBy(o => o.SomeProperty).Count() == theList.Count;` while Distinct() does not allow that.

Answer (score 1):

I check if an IEnumerable (aray, list, etc ) is unique like this :

```
var isUnique = someObjectsEnum.GroupBy(o => o.SomeProperty).Max(g => g.Count()) == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also do: Use Hashset

```
var uniqueIds = new HashSet<long>(originalList.Select(item => item.Id));

            if (uniqueIds.Count != originalList.Count)
            {
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many solutions.

And no doubt more beautiful ones with the usage of LINQ as "juergen d" and "Tim Schmelter" mentioned.

But, if you bare "Complexity" and speed, the best solution will be to implement it by yourself.
One of the solution will be, to create an array of N size (for byte it's 256).
And loop the array, and on every iteration will test the matching number index if the value is 1 if it does, that means i already increment the array index and therefore the array isn't distinct otherwise i will increment the array cell and continue checking.

Comment: you can use a bit vector with 256 bits = 32 byte = 8 integers. But your Big O = O(n) still will be the same as using a Hashet proposed in the other answer.

Comment: This is O(n) so maybe fastest, (test it). Would checking counts as you go or at the end be the quickest? I suspect that at the end will improve worst case, but as you go may improve average and best case). If there is no duplicates this will be worst case performance. Also for bigger data types this will not work well, for a 16bit type you would have to use 64k of count, well 64k bit (8k byte), but for anything bigger the memory usage will start to get silly. However I like this answer for 8bit values.

Comment: @TamusJRoyce if you want to store 4294967296 possibilities, you need 4GB not 42MB (or 512MB of you use bit masking)

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking. "Allocate 42MB+ of memory to hold all 4294967296 possibilities. And use simple bucket counters. Or even use bit masking xor and check if any bit is changed from true to false. 42MB+ / 8 = 5MB+ The expense seems too great with today's hardware. But one day this may hold merit." isn't really a relevant comment. Hashset would be best. If you are dealing with extremely large arrays, you expect extremely large piece of memory. But in such a strange edge case, a heristic with a CRC algorithm would be better. Map it to a polynomial. If close, evaluate. Thank you @tigrou!

Answer (score -1):

And another solution, if you want to find duplicated values.

```
var values = new [] { 9, 7, 2, 6, 7, 3, 8, 2 };

var sorted = values.ToList();
sorted.Sort();
for (var index = 1; index < sorted.Count; index++)
{
    var previous = sorted[index - 1];
    var current = sorted[index];
    if (current == previous)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("duplicated value: {0}", current));
}
```

Output:

```
duplicated value: 2
duplicated value: 7
```

http://rextester.com/SIDG48202