# How I can validate ten comboboxes for the same value?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have 10 comboboxes with players. In each combobox must be selected one player. Now, I must validate their so, that only one unique player can be selected in combobox.

For example:

combobox1 - Anna

combobox2 - Anna (too)

But if Anna is selected I don't want choose she in another combobox. Or I can show error message on click button "Start Game", that Anna is selected in two comboboxes. The main thing it must be validate. I have only one Idea how I ca validate this and it's not the best way.

```
if cmbPlayer1.SelectedValue = cmbPlayer2.SelectedValue Or
   cmbPlayer1.SelectedValue = cmbPlayer2.SelectedValue Or
   ...
   cmbPlayer1.SelectedValue = cmbPlayer10.SelectedValue
```

and so for each of ten combobox.

How I can do it better?

Comment: The answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303897/test-if-all-values-in-a-list-are-unique) is quite useful. You could put each value into a collection and test that way.

Comment: Personally, I would tend to filter the remaining lists when a selection is made, thus ensuring that the user can't possibly select duplicates. It's a bit more code but it's a better UX. Prevention is generally better than cure.

Comment: Can you put the names in one list box and set the Selection Mode so the user can make 10 selections in on list box? No duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create List of all selected value of value.

```
List<Player> players=new List<Player>
palyers.add(cmbPlayer1.SelectedValue)
```

upto 10 Players.

Then check unique values

```
palyers.Distinct().Count()==10
```

Answer (score 0):

How bout this

I tried with one combobox with bunch of names inside,and one listbox to show 10 players that have selected on the combobox. i make a condition like this :

If you select the same name it will shows an message "Multiple name detected". Else if you didn't do that you'll able to add another name to listbox.

So i make the "prevention" condition when selecting names,not when the button pressed.

Try to add a listbox and combobox,fill the listbox value with names. And make the name appear on listbox when you select it.

And code like this on the combobox

```
  Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Not ListBox1.Items.Contains(ComboBox1.Text) Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
    Else
        MsgBox("Multiple name detected")
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this will help you,and sorry for my bad english.