# how to compare the elements of a single array between themselves

Tags: c#

I would like to compare the elements of a array fed by random values to see if this value has not been added a second time in my array

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    int[] elements = new int[8];
    int lo = rand.Next(1, 49);
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
    {
        lo = rand.Next(1, 49);
        elements[i] = lo;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
    {
        if (elements[i] == elements[elements.Length - 2])
        {

        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < elements.Length; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(elements[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use standard `HashSet<int>`? It guarantees that elements would be unique

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think this is related, and even answered by @TimSchmelter https://stackoverflow.com/a/18304070/7002366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers correctly solves your problem of detecting if there are any duplicate entries using `GroupBy`. However, if your intent is to replace those duplicate entries with new non-existing entry in the array, you can use the methods below -

```
        Random rand = new Random();

        int[] elements = new int[8];
        int lo;
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
        {
            do
                lo = rand.Next(1, 49);
            while (elements.Contains(lo));
            elements[i] = lo;
            Console.WriteLine(elements[i]);
        }
```

This code will guarantee that `elements` array will always have unique values.

Note :- `do...while` loop keep generating random numbers unless it finds a unique number. So if your array size is bigger then the range of random numbers generated you'll get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer which is excellent and precise and which has met my expectations

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var hasDuplicates = elements
    .GroupBy(entry => entry)
    .Select(group => new { Entry = group.Key, Count = group.Count() })
    .Where(group => group.Count > 1).Count() > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the power of linq you can use the `GroupBy` to find your duplicates.

Also, `Enumerable.Range` is a quick way of generating lists.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var rand = new Random();

    var elements = Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Select(_ => rand.Next(1, 49));

    var duplicates = elements.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).ToArray();

    if (duplicates.Any())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("duplicates found");  
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("no duplicates"); 
    }
}
```

If you need to act on the duplicates you can iterate them and use `.Key`