# Linq on DateTime Collections Best Performance

Tags: c#, linq

My app has a Collection of Job objects. There is a unique property (Key) called Jobnumber and a DateTime property called Bookingtime which is not necessarily unique. There are various other properties also.

I want to do a lot of linq queries based on the Bookingtime property and occasional inserts and removal of objects from the collection.

If I have 1000 to 2000 objects in a collection should I use a `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` or just a `List<T>` and order it manually with linq?

Does the options change for 10,000 objects in the collection?

The objects are from database and are already sorted by Bookingtime but I need to work on certain datetime subsets.

```
DateTime t1,t2; //equals some values.
var subSet = jobs.where(a=>a.Bookingtime >= t1 &&
a.Bookingtime < =    t2).ToList();
```

Comment: A SortedList would require an unique key for sure. If you would give some examples of what the querys would look like we can give better answers.

Comment: If the number of date-based queries greatly exceeds the number of updates, then I'd go for a sorted collection.

Comment: @user3812046: the data is already sorted?? Why don't you query the database immediately with the constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one can see in the documentation, the [`SortedList.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (too bad there is no `AddAll` method as in *Java* that could optimize bulk insertion) operation is performed in *O(n)* whereas [`OrderBy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799427/what-guarantees-are-there-on-the-run-time-complexity-big-o-of-linq-methods) runs in *O(n log n)*. The implication is that only on small (or sorted lists), the `SortedList` *can* outperform *Linq*.

Furthermore notice that *Linq* uses lazy evaluation. It will only sort items if you actually need the resulting list (or use a `ToList`,... method). If you thus later never do anything with the result, the environment won't even sort the data.

[This article](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/04/a_truly_lazy_orderby_in_linq.html) even implements a truly lazy `OrderBy`, such that if you only need the first `i` items, it will not sort the entire list.

**EDIT**: based on the your updated question, you better incorporate the `.where` statement as a `WHERE` in the SQL query. This can reduce network, memory and CPU usage since a database in many cases has means to optimize queries enormously.

Comment: Sure I do I pull in the 1 months worth of bookings and need to query diffrent subsets of that collection for differing scenarios.

Comment: I was just wondering if you need a subset of those objects what would be quicker.

Comment: @user3812046: for such small subsets (and fast tests), I wonder if this will make much difference. Perhaps you should run some benchmarks.