# Merge two Lists of different types

Tags: c#, list

I add data to the objects of a List from another List:

```
public void MergeLsts(List<A> lstA, List<B> lstB)
{
    foreach (A dataA in lstA)
    {
        foreach (B dataB in lstB)
        {
            if (dataA.ItemNo == dataB.ItemNo)
            {
                //dataA.ItemDescription is up to this point empty!
                dataA.ItemDescription = dataB.ItemDescription;
            }
        }
    }
    DoSomethingWithTheNewLst(lstA);
}
```

This works perfectly fine. However it takes pretty long because both lists get quite large (around 70k items in lstA and 20k items in lstB).

I was wondering if there is a faster or more efficient way to accomplish what I need? Maybe with LINQ?

Comment: If the collections are the same length you can use .Zip()

Comment: I assume that you can order the data in ItemNo. If you want to do this manually (not using some library function), you could do this: sort both lists by ItemNo, add the data in a way akin to the merge step in merge sort. This should work in nlogn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `O(n)` complexity instead of `O(N²)` with `Join()`:

```
var joinedData =  dataA.Join(dataB, dA => dA.ItemNo, dB => dB.ItemNo, (dA, dB) => new { dA, dB }));
foreach(var pair in joinedData)
{
    pair.dA.ItemDescription = pair.dB.ItemDescription;
}
```

`Distinct`, `GroupBy` and `Join` operations use hashing, so they should be close to `O(N)` instead of `O(N²)`.

Comment: Doesnt Join have a complexity of O(n^2) itself? So your solution would be O(n^3)

Comment: Just found out that they are [close to O(n)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799427/what-guarantees-are-there-on-the-run-time-complexity-big-o-of-linq-methods). So your solution has a complexity of (n^2), not O(n)

Comment: @Domysee no, my solution has a O(2n) complexity that is an equivalent to O(n). I'm iterate N elements twice and O(n^2) says that N elements iterates N times.

Comment: Right, my bad. Sorry about that

Comment: Btw: this solution is 23 (!) seconds faster than my original approach

Comment: I just realized that something is not right: In my case dataA contains around 73.000 entrys, but joinedData contains only around 70.000 entrys. Why are 3000 entrys missing?

Comment: @Tobio'Bobi It's OK. `joinedData` contains only data from `dataA` that has an equivalent in `dataB`. Inside the loop we are updating source objects (we are not creating new `A` objects) then (because `A` is a reference type) `dataA` collection will contains updated (with changed `ItemDescription`) objects as expected.