# Merge 2 List of Objects, no duplicates, based on comparison

Tags: c#

I need to merge 2 lists of objects, they share the same interface, but different concrete class.

The result should contain a List of new Objects based on each concrete class, and set a property on each object based on a comparison of the same objects from the lists.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<IStuff> stuffList1 = new List<IStuff>();
        List<IStuff> stuffList2 = new List<IStuff>();

        stuffList1.Add(new Toaster
        {
            ValueOfMyThing = 1
        });
        stuffList1.Add(new Car
        {
            ValueOfMyThing = 3
        });
        stuffList1.Add(new Onion
        {
            ValueOfMyThing = 3
        });

        stuffList2.Add(new Toaster
        {
            ValueOfMyThing = 2
        });
        stuffList2.Add(new Car
        {
            ValueOfMyThing = 1
        });
        stuffList2.Add(new Onion
        {
            ValueOfMyThing = 5
        });

        List<IStuff> stuffList3 = new List<IStuff>();            

        // Need to merge stuffList1 and stuffList2 taking the stuff that has the higher valueOfMyThing
        // The result should be a stuffList3 with a Toaster 2 a Car 3 and an Onion 5
    }
}
interface IStuff
{
    int ValueOfMyThing { get; set; }
}

class Toaster: IStuff
{
    public int ValueOfMyThing { get; set; }
}
class Car : IStuff
{
    public int ValueOfMyThing { get; set; }
}
class Onion : IStuff
{
    public int ValueOfMyThing { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so fat? Have you googled merging lists of custom types? Hint: have a look at linq's `Concat` and `Distinct` and then `GetHashCode` and `Equals`

Comment: Your interface is empty even if all classes use `valueOfMyThing`. You notice what you are missing?

Comment: Or you can use a HashSet<IStuff>

Comment: Also, you say you want a Car/3 in the final list, but there is no car with `valueOfMyThing=3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need the common property in the interface, otherwise you can't use polymoprhism to access it when you enumerate the items in the `List<IStuff>`:

```
interface IStuff
{
    int ValueOfMyThing { get; set; }
}
```

Now add this property to the classes as well (omitted).

Then you could use this LINQ query to group by the concrete type, for example `Car`, and get the item with the highest `ValueOfMyThing` for each group:

```
List<IStuff> stuffList3 = stuffList1.Concat(stuffList2)
    .GroupBy(x => x.GetType())
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.ValueOfMyThing).First())
    .ToList();
```

> This works, but I need stuffList3 to contain new Instances

Then you could provide a method to copy existing instances to new:

```
public interface IStuff
{
    int ValueOfMyThing { get; set; }
    IStuff Copy();
}
```

add it to your classes:

```
public class Toaster : IStuff
{
    public int ValueOfMyThing { get; set; }
    public IStuff Copy()
    {
        return new Toaster { ValueOfMyThing = ValueOfMyThing };
    }
}
// ...
```

and call `Copy`:

```
List<IStuff> stuffList3 = stuffList1.Concat(stuffList2)
    .GroupBy(x => x.GetType())
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.ValueOfMyThing).First().Copy())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This works, but I need stuffList3  to contain new Instances

Answer (score 0):

Frist, you need to let `valueOfMyThing` property or field in `IStuff` interface be a contract for classes.

```
interface IStuff
{
    int valueOfMyThing { get; set; }
}

class Toaster : IStuff
{
    public int valueOfMyThing { get; set; }
}
class Car : IStuff
{
    public int valueOfMyThing { get; set; }
}
class Onion : IStuff
{
    public int valueOfMyThing { get; set; }
}
```

Then add this extension method to allow a Distinct Query with lambda parameters:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this 
    IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();

    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        if (keySelector != null && seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally use it on your list.

```
List<IStuff> stuffList3 = new List<IStuff>();

stuffList3.AddRange(stuffList2);
stuffList3.AddRange(stuffList1);

var r = stuffList3.DistinctBy(x => x.valueOfMyThing);
```

Comment: There's no Distinct overload that takes a lambda, this doesn't compile without further extensions that you might have omitted.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create new instance of the objects. So I ended up doing this: 
First as mentioned by Tim Schmelmer:

```
interface IStuff
{
    int ValueOfMyThing { get; set; }
}

class Toaster: IStuff
{
    public int ValueOfMyThing { get; set; }
}
class Car : IStuff
{
    public int ValueOfMyThing { get; set; }
}
class Onion : IStuff
{
    public int ValueOfMyThing { get; set; }
}
```

Then based on this answer [Merge two Lists of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128723/merge-two-lists-of-different-types)

```
        List<IStuff> stuffList3 = new List<IStuff>();

        var joinedData = stuffList1.Join(stuffList2, sl1 => sl1.GetType(), sl2 => sl2.GetType(), (sl1, sl2) => new { sl1, sl2 });
        foreach (var pair in joinedData)
        {
            var newStuffValue = Math.Max(pair.sl1.ValueOfMyThing, pair.sl2.ValueOfMyThing);
            var newStuff = (IStuff)Activator.CreateInstance(pair.sl1.GetType());
            newStuff.ValueOfMyThing = newStuffValue;
            stuffList3.Add(newStuff);

        }
```

Now I´ve got a list of new concrete classes, but I´m not sure this is the best approach