# Comparing two list of different objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have following list.

One list with Person object has Id & Name property. Other list with People object has Id, Name & Address property.

```
List<Person> p1 = new List<Person>();
p1.Add(new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "a" });
p1.Add(new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "b" });
p1.Add(new Person() { Id = 3, Name = "c" });
p1.Add(new Person() { Id = 4, Name = "d" });

List<People> p2 = new List<People>();
p2.Add(new People() { Id = 1, Name = "a", Address=100 });
p2.Add(new People() { Id = 3, Name = "x", Address=101 });
p2.Add(new People() { Id = 4, Name = "y", Address=102 });
p2.Add(new People() { Id = 8, Name = "z", Address=103 });
```

Want to filter list so I used below code. But code returns List of Ids. I want List of People object with matched Ids.

```
var filteredList = p2.Select(y => y.Id).Intersect(p1.Select(z => z.Id));
```

Comment: `Join` p1 and p2 on Id

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you just want a list of people where the same Id exists in the Person collection?

Comment: How is it possible that the same 'Id' of a 'Person' has different name?
And what is exactly that you want to achieve?

Comment: Kindly ignore values in the list. These are dummy values. Need list of people where same Id exists in the person class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're better off with `Join`

```
var filteredList = p2.Join(p1, 
        people => people.Id, 
        person => person.Id, 
        (people, _) => people)
    .ToList();
```

The method will match items from both lists by the key you provide - `Id` of the `People` class and `Id` of `Person` class.
For each pair where `people.Id == person.Id` it applies the selector function `(people, _) => people`. The function says *for each pair of matched `people` and `person` just give me the `people` instance; I don't care about `person`*.

Comment: Can you please explain how it works. I don't understand -  p=>p.Id, p=>p.Id, (people, _)=>people

Comment: @user2323308 - Please check is [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/2994/joins-inner-left-right-cross-and-full-outer-joins#t=201608191121456680136)

Comment: In simple words: find intersection `p2` with `p1` by `Id` field in p2 and `ID` in `p1` and from pair of `p2_item` and p`1_item` select `p2_item`

Comment: @GiladGreen - I know different types of joins. But syntax in the answer unable to understand. What is significance of (People, _) in the above answer

Comment: the `_` is just the name of the parameter that he chose

Comment: @user2323308 _ is a name of variable, same as p, a, v,..... In this case _ is an object of Person type

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick :

```
var result= p1.Join(p2, person => person.Id, people => people.Id, (person, people) => people);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list is large enough you should use hashed collection to filter it and *improve performance*:

```
var hashedIds = new HashSet<int>(p1.Select(p => p.Id));
var filteredList = p2.Where(p => hashedIds.Contains(p.Id)).ToList();
```

This will work and work extremely fast because Hashed collections like Dictionary or HashSet allows to perform fast lookups with almost `O(1)` complexity (which effectively means that in order to find element with certain hash compiler knows exactly where to look for it. And with `List<T>` to find certain element compiler would have to loop the entire collection in order to find it.

For example line:  `p2.Where(p => p1.Contains(p.Id)).ToList();`
has complexity of O(N2) because using of both .Where and .Contains will form nested loops.

Do not use the simplest answer (and method), use the one that better suits your needs.

[Simple performance test against .Join() ...](http://rextester.com/YPJ46436)

And the larger collection is the more difference it would make.

Comment: You are right that this will work much faster but maybe explain why :)

Comment: Join complexity: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2799543/1506454; as for performance test, if number of unique Ids not 100 in 20k, but 20k in 20k, `Join` is pretty fast

Comment: @ASh Yes, `Join()` method is optimized and it's complexity is good but not  better than Where+Contains using HashTable. The problem with Join is that it does some additional checks and other operations that reduce the overall performance.