# What is the most efficient way to join two lists in C# on a common field?

Tags: c#, linq

Could you tell me which one of those list joining methods is more efficient and why? Or is it the same performance-wise? Is there any other approach to this situation (joining 2 lists based on field property)?

My code:

```
public List<CombinedDatabaseStructure> Combine1(List<DatabaseStructure1> _Data1, List<DatabaseStructure2> _Data2)
{
    List<CombinedDatabaseStructure> combinedAll = new List<CombinedDatabaseStructure>();
    foreach (var row1 in _Data1)
    {
        foreach (var row2 in _Data2)
        {
            CombinedDatabaseStructure combined = new CombinedDatabaseStructure();
            if (row1.ID == row2.ID)
            {
                combined.DatabaseStructure1 = row1;
                combined.DatabaseStructure2 = row2;
                combinedAll.Add(combined);
            }
        }
    }

    return combinedAll;
}
```

Code2:

```
public List<CombinedDatabaseStructure> Combine2(List<DatabaseStructure1> _Data1, List<DatabaseStructure2> _Data2)
{
    var joined = from item1 in _Data1.AsEnumerable() 
                 join item2 in _Data2.AsEnumerable() on item1.ID equals item2.ID
                 select new CombinedDatabaseStructure (item1,item2);

    return  joined.ToList<CombinedDatabaseStructure>();
}
```

Comment: When you profiled it, what did you find? _Also, you will probably find you could remove your `.AsEnumerable()` code - it doesn't achieve anything._

Comment: Where is the list data coming from? e.g. is it coming from a database?

Comment: The only way to prove which is the best is to test yourself, nobody else can tell you that.

Comment: @mjwills yes, it's coming from DB

Comment: In that case, I would recommend getting the DB to do the join. It will be massively more efficient.

Comment: @mjwills the thing is I'm getting data1 from SQL Database and data2 from Oracle Database and stored procedure approach (linked servers) is a no-go :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a general rule: If there's a built-in method in the .NET framework which does exactly what you want, it's *usually* a good idea to use it instead of re-implementing it. It's easier, more readable, less error-prone, better tested and *usually* more efficiently implemented.

---

Let's look at your particular problem in detail:

Option 1 is basically a manual (naive) implementation of a nested loop join with a complexity of `O(n*m)`.

Option 2 uses LINQ-to-object's implementation of `join`, which [internally uses a hash join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2799543/87698), which has a complexity of `O(n+m)`.

If you are worried about efficiency, I'd recommend "Option 3": **let the database do the join**. It can use statistics to choose the optimal join strategy for your data.

---

Note: Your nested loop implementation is very inefficient. It can be implemented with `O(n*log(m))` complexity by using some kind of index lookup to find matching Data2 rows instead of the inner loop. In that case, a nested loop join *can* be faster than a hash join, [if `n` is very small and `m` is large](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/938/5273). This, however, assumes that the index already exists, since creating an index (for example, by creating a C# dictionary from your list) is a `O(m)` operation itself.