# Efficient way of grouping characters in string c#

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I want an efficient way of grouping strings whilst keeping duplicates and order.
Something like this

```
1100110002200   -> 101020
```

I tried this previously

```
_case.GroupBy(c => c).Select(g => g.Key)
```

but I got 102

But this gives me what I want, I just want to optimize it, so I wouldn't have to scour the entire list each time

```
static List<char> group(string _case)
{
    var groups = new List<char>();
    for (int i = 0; i < _case.Length; i++)
    {
        if (groups.LastOrDefault() != _case[i])
            groups.Add(_case[i]);
    }
    return groups;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a better suit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) since you have working code that you want to improve, but be sure to check [what's on topic there](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What does "scour the entire list each time" mean? (Note: [for a List, `LastOrDefault` is an O(1) operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2799543/2864740).) How does it differ from "scouring" with GroupBy/Select/LINQ?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks, I will check there right away

Comment: @user2864740 I meant to request for a more efficient option, scouring the list with groupby is something I expect to be done in a more optimized manner. My expectations may be unattainable in some cases though

Comment: I think your approach is pretty good TBH. It's about as non-scoury as you're likely to get (a single pass with indexed O(1) lookups). I wouldn't expect anything in LINQ-to-Objects to be this efficient.

Comment: OK, thank you all very much. At least I can sleep without worry for now.

Comment: I would use : _case.GroupBy(c => c).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng That doesn't do what he wants to though.

Comment: John, are you sure?

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I am. He wants to take `1100110002200` and get `101020`. GroupBy will not do this as it will take all of the 1s and make a single group, another for the 0s, another for the 2s, etc.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking... Code shown in the post is O(string_length), there is nothing you can do to make it algorithmically faster. You can experiment with counting length first or caching last character...

Comment: Are you sure it is not a key and a value?

Comment: Thank you all, I will try out Lejsek's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I like the elegant solution of rshepp, it turns out that the very basic code can run even 5 times faster than that.

```
public static string Simplify2(string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) { return str; }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char last = str[0];
    sb.Append(last);

    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if (last != c)
        {
            sb.Append(c);
            last = c;
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create a method that loops each character and checks the previous character for equality. If they aren't the same, append/yield return the character. This is pretty easy to do with Linq.

```
public static string Simplify(string str)
{
    return string.Concat(str.Where((c, i) => i == 0 || c != str[i - 1]));
}
```

Usage:

```
string simplified = Simplify("1100110002200");
// 101020
```

In my testing, my method and yours are roughly equal in speed, mine being insignificantly slower after 10 million executions (4260ms vs 4241ms).

However, my method returns the result as a string whereas yours doesn't. If you need to convert your result back to a string (which is likely) then my method is indeed much faster/more efficient (4260ms vs 6569ms).