# Can I use LINQ to find out if a given property in a list repeats itself?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects that have a name field on them.

I want to know if there's a way to tell if all the name fields are unique in the list.

I could just do two loops and iterate over the list for each value, but I wanted to know if there's a cleaner way to do this using LINQ?

I've found a few examples where they compare each item of the list to a hard coded value but in my case I want to compare the name field on each object between each other and obtain a boolean value.

Comment: Post the code you currently have, we cant help you otherwise

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com please show us your code

Comment: You can use LINQ GroupBy name, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Answer (score 7):

A common "trick" to check for uniqueness is to compare the length of a list with duplicates removed with the length of the original list:

```
bool allNamesAreUnique = myList.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().Count() == myList.Count();
```

- `Select(x => x.Name)` transforms your list into a list of just the names, and
- `Distict()` removes the duplicates.

The performance should be [close to `O(n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2799427/87698), which is better than the `O(n²)` nested-loop solution.

---

Another option is to group your list by the name and check the size of those groups. This has the additional advantage of telling you which values are not unique:

```
var duplicates = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);

bool hasDuplicates = duplicates.Any();  // or
List<string> duplicateNames = duplicates.Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Code only answers are not very helpful

Comment: @maccettura: I fully agree. I usually answer quickly with a code-only answer (to prevent others from wasting time and effort into writing the same answer) and then expand it with explanations. You were just too quick in spotting my answer. :-)

Comment: A good strategy - I was just starting to write up the same answer when you posted.

Comment: @J.L There's a similar solution using `GroupBy` and checking for any groups bigger than 1. This has the added benefit of telling what the duplicate *is*

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Good point, I have added this option to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use LINQ to group or create a distinct list, and then compare item-wise with the original list, that incurs a bit of overhead you might not want, especially for a very large list. A more efficient solution would store the keys in a HashSet, which has better lookup capability, and check for duplicates in a single loop. This solution still uses a little bit of LINQ so it satisfies your requirements.

```
static public class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public bool HasDuplicates<TItem,TKey>(this IEnumerable<TItem> source, Func<TItem,TKey> func)
    {
        var found = new HashSet<TKey>();
        foreach (var key in source.Select(func))
        {
            if (found.Contains(key)) return true;
            found.Add(key);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you are looking for duplicates in a field named `Name`, use it like this:

```
var hasDuplicates = list.HasDuplicates( item => item.Name );
```

If you want case-insensitivity:

```
var hasDuplicates = list.HasDuplicates( item => item.Name.ToUpper() );
```

Comment: I like your solution because it stops traversing the list as soon as the first duplicate is found. (I don't like `This` starting with an uppercase letter, but that might just be me. [Linq uses `source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx) as a name for the "this" parameter.)