# Implementing a LINQ "chunk by predicate" with O(1) memory, O(n) runtime complexity and no double-enumeration

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq, data-structures

***Examples:*** Suppose the predicate is `i == 0`.

Then

- [1] -> [(1)]
- [0] -> []
- [1, 0] -> [(1)]
- [0, 1] -> [(1)]
- [0, 0] -> []
- [1, 1, 0] -> [(1, 1)]
- [1, 0, 1] -> [(1), (1)]
- [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1] -> [(1, 1), (1), (1, 1, 1)]

Basically, returning contiguous subsegments where the predicate is false.

I thought this would work

```
internal static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PartitionBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> condition)
{
    IEnumerator<T> mover = source.GetEnumerator();

    for (; mover.MoveNext() ; )
    {
        var chunk = mover.MoveUntil(condition);

        if (chunk.Any())
        {
            yield return chunk;
        }
    }          
}

private static IEnumerable<T> MoveUntil<T>(this IEnumerator<T> mover, Func<T, bool> condition)
{
    bool hitCondition = false;

    do
    {
        if (condition(mover.Current))
        {
            hitCondition = true;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return mover.Current;
        }
    }
    while (!hitCondition && mover.MoveNext());
}
```

but I was seeing that for example with [1, 1, 0] it will return  [(1), (1)]. I don't completely understand why. I can make it work if I change

```
var chunk = mover.MoveUntil(condition);
```

to have `mover.MoveUntil(condition).ToList();` but if possible I'd like to not have to hold any of the subsegments in memory.

Comment: I don't understand your expected results, particularly the last one. Also, it would be easier to understand if every number wasn't 1 or 0. Use some 2, 3 etc.

Comment: @mjwills I had a slight type-o in the last one. Just fixed it. To explain, if you have `[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]` and the predicate is `i == 0`, then you want all subsegments that are separated by one or more `0`s, so those will be the first 2 numbers `(1, 1)`, the 1 in the middle `(1)`, then the last 3 `(1, 1, 1)`.

Comment: Is iterating the sequence multiple times acceptable? (I.e. by storing starting position for each inner enumerable)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Ideally not. That's what I meant by "no double-enumeration" in title.

Comment: It would be easier to understand if every number wasn't 1 or 0. Use some 2, 3 etc. This is important to understand to see whether `GroupAdjacent` is an option or not.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I think you wanted O(n) as memory complexity, as your output length is linearly proportional to the input. As a big fan of functional programming, I have chosen to use a fold (that corresponds to the LINQ function `Aggregate` in C#).

Basically, we start with an empty collection of collection and a flag that indicates whether the next iteration has to create a new sub-collection (we only know that when the predicate matches, i.e. in the previous iteration). I use a tuple that contains those two elements as an accumulator. I extracted the logic of the Aggregate in a separated function for clarity purpose.

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    // The accumulator is a tuple defined as: (collection, mustCreateNewList)
    return a.Aggregate((new List<List<T>>(), true), (acc, e) => ForEachElement(acc, e, predicate)).Item1;
}

static (List<List<T>>, bool) ForEachElement<T>((List<List<T>>, bool) acc, T e, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var (collection, mustCreateNewList) = acc;

    // The predicate matches, continue to iterate!
    if (predicate(e)) return (collection, true);

    // The previous iteration requests to create a new list
    if(mustCreateNewList) collection.Add(new List<T>());

    // Add the current element to the last list
    collection[collection.Count - 1].Add(e);

    return (collection, false);
}
```

The initial collection is walked through once (O(n)) and the length of the output has the length of the input in the worst case (O(n)).

Example of call:

```
var array = new int[] { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
var result = array.Partition(i => i == 0);
```

Comment: I guess I meant "O(1) memory at any given time during the enumeration"

Comment: I'm sorry, but that statement does not make sense to me. In a global manner, you request the output to have a size between 0 and n, where n is the number of non matching element according the predicate. That means the the output size is bound to the input size, hence n. The code I provided only allocate one-list/element at each iteration. I don't know if there is what you are referring by "any given time during the enumeration" ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to stream the results using LINQ calls. The below implementation:

1. Does not create temporary `List`s to reduce memory consumption, I think it would be `O(1)` for the memory as only one sub-segment is dealt with at a time.
2. There will be no double enumeration and the predicate will be called exactly once per record.
3. It would be `O(n)` for the runtime because like [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2799543/197371), the `GroupBy` operation should be `O(n)` and the other LINQ calls are single-pass operations so should also be `O(n)`.

```cs
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PartitionBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        int groupNumber = 0;
        Func<bool, int?> getGroupNumber = skip =>
        {
            if (skip)
            {
                // prepare next group, we don't care if we increment more than once
                // we only want to split groups
                groupNumber++;
                // null, to be able to filter out group separators
                return null;
            }
            return groupNumber;
        };
        return a
            .Select(x => new { Value = x, GroupNumber = getGroupNumber(predicate(x))} )
            .Where(x => x.GroupNumber != null)
            .GroupBy(x => x.GroupNumber)
            .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Value));       
    }
```