# How to OrderBy() as per the order requested in distinct string list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

How to use OrderBy for shaping output in the same order as per the requested distinct list

```
    public DataCollectionList GetLatestDataCollection(List<string> requestedDataPointList)
    {
        var dataPoints = _context.DataPoints.Where(c => requestedDataPointList.Contains(c.dataPointName))
                                 .OrderBy(----------)  //TODO: RE-ORDER IN THE SAME ORDER AS REQUESTED requestedDataPointList
                                 .ToList();        
        
         
        dataPoints.ForEach(dp => 
        {
           ....
        });

    }
```

Comment: Loop over the requestDataPointList and add each DataPoint to a new List

Comment: You query is backwards.  It should be : requestedDataPointList.SelectMany(x => _context.DataPoints.Where(c => x.Contains(c.dataPointName)))

Comment: If i loop it will be 5000 calls to DB i don't wish to loop it

Comment: then `requestedDataPointList.SelectMany(x=>dataPoints.Where(c => x == c.dataPointName))` and remove OrderBy

Comment: Then add a intermediate query  :           var temp = requestedDataPointList.Select((x,i) => new { name = x, index = i});
            var dataPoints = _context.DataPoints.SelectMany(c => temp.Where(x => x.name.Contains(c.dataPointName))
                .Select(x => new { point = c, index = x.index }))
                .OrderBy(x => x.index);

Comment: @Selvin I don't see how that helps - that still generates one query per member of `requestedDataPointList`.

Comment: @jdweng EF Core won't translate that `SelectMany`.

Comment: @NetMage no, obviousy it will not generate any query ... as it use `dataPoints` which is already "materialized" with `ToList()`

Comment: @Selvin I see what you mean.

Comment: Check the syntax.  The code did not give me any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Do the sorting on the client side:

```
public DataCollectionList GetLatestDataCollection(List<string> requestedDataPointList)
{
    var dataPoints = _context.DataPoints.Where(c => requestedDataPointList.Contains(c.dataPointName))
                             .AsEnumerable()
                             .OrderBy(requestedDataPointList.IndexOf(c.dataPointName));        
    
    foreach (var dp in dataPoints)
    {
       ....
    });

}
```

NOTE: Also, I don't think `ToList().ForEach()` is ever better than `foreach ()`.

Answer (score 1):

It think the fastest method is to join the result back with the request list. This makes use of the fact that LINQ's `join` preserves the sort order of the first list:

```cs
var dataPoints = _context.DataPoints
    .Where(c => requestedDataPointList.Contains(c.dataPointName))
    .ToList();

var ordered = from n in requestedDataPointList
              join dp in dataPoints on n equals dp.dataPointName
              select dp;

foreach (var dataPoint in ordered)
{
    ...
}
```

This doesn't involve any ordering, joining does it all, which will be [close to O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2799543/861716).

Another fast method consists of creating a dictionary of sequence numbers:

```cs
var indexes = requestedDataPointList
    .Select((n, i) => new { n, i }).ToDictionary(x => x.n, x => x.i);
var ordered = dataPoints.OrderBy(dp => indexes[dp.dataPointName]);
```